# How do I scroll to the bottom of a page using Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, electron, cheerio, nightmare

I want to write a Web Scraper using NightmareJS and Cheerio. The Code is working but since the website is dynamic and is only loading new entries while scrolling down, I need to reach the bottom of the page.

I've already tried different types and also .scrollTo().
.scrollTo doesn't work, so the page doesn't scroll down. Any other solution provided on the web doesn't let the program even start.

<< Scrolling to bottom here >> show's you where it should be scrolled down.

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('Request');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('post6.csv');

// Write Headers
writeStream.write(`Artists \n`);

// We initialize the nightmare and set the show property to true to monitor...
// ...what the browser is doing on execution.
const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})
const url = 'https://www.ujomusic.com/';

// Request making using Nightmare
nightmare
// Request to url through goto function
  .goto(url)
// Waiting for the DOM to be rendered through wait function (without no rendering).
  .wait('body')
  .click('#__next > div:nth-child(1) > div.navigation-portal-container > div.nav-third.text-left > a')
  .wait(3000)


//  << Scrolling to bottom here >>



// When body completely loaded, innerHTML is fetched using evaluate...
// ... also data are returned.
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
// Browser is getting closed by calling end function.
  .end()
// You could also use try/catch blocks but using promises, .then() must be...
// called after .end() to run the .end() task.
  .then(response => {
    console.log(getData(response));
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  // Parsing data using cheerio
  let getData = html => {
    data = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  //each function Iteriert über ein Cheerio-Objekt und führt für jedes passende Element eine Funktion aus.

  $('.col-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3.col-hu-2.margin-bottom-md').each((i, el) => {
    const artists = $(el)
      .find('.text-body.text-truncate.text-truncate.release-tile-music-group-name')
      .text();
    // const link = $(el)
    //   .find('a')
    //   .attr('href');

      // Write Row to CSV
      writeStream.write(`${artists} \n`);

      console.log('Scraping Done...');

  });
}
```

I expect the code to open the page, scroll completely to the bottom till there are no new entries loaded, **scraping** the data and giving me the outcome in a .csv file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scrollTo` should work. Are you sure you used it in the right way? Something like `.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, 9999999))` would scroll to the bottom - but you'd have to wait for more things to load of course and identify when there is nothing more to come.